# Help with Navigation - Error "transform from /base_link to /map"

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, base-link, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello There!

I am having a hard time to get the Navigation Stack running on a robot ([Traxbot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/traxbot_robot)), to which it was added an Hokuyo laser sensor.

I was able to follow the navigation [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) smoothly, broadcasting the base_laser→base_link transform, publishing a sensor_msgs/LaserScan using [hokuyo_node](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node), publishing the nav_msgs/Odometry message over ROS and a transforming from a "/odom" coordinate frame to "/base_link", as well as receiving velocity commands and passing them on to the robot. I have also created a very simple map of a square arena.

All of these issues have been tested and seem to be working just fine.

Then, I have created the launch file to bring up the robot's configurations as well as the navigation stack (with AMCL), following the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) instructions.

So, when I roslaunch my "traxbot_config.launch", everything works fine:

```
NODES
 /
  robot_node (traxbot_robot/robot_node)
  hokuyo_node (hokuyo_node/hokuyo_node)
  traxbot_static_tf_laser (mrl_tf_setup/traxbot_static_tf_laser)

  ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

  core service [/rosout] found
  process[robot_node-1]: started with pid [8014]
  process[hokuyo_node-2]: started with pid [8015]
  process[traxbot_static_tf_laser-3]: started with pid [8016]
  [ WARN] [1338989473.365252155]: The use_rep_117 parameter has not been set or is set to false.  Please see: http://ros.org/wiki/rep_117/migration
  [ INFO] [1338989473.518591684]: Robot -- Successfully connected to the Robot!
```

Then, I roslaunch the navstack ("move_base_square_map.launch"), and I get the following output:

```
NODES
 /
   map_server (map_server/map_server)
   amcl (amcl/amcl)
   move_base (move_base/move_base)

   ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

   core service [/rosout] found
   process[map_server-1]: started with pid [2187]
   process[amcl-2]: started with pid [2188]
   process[move_base-3]: started with pid [2189]
   [ INFO] [1339006055.653083864]: Subscribed to Topics: laser_scan_sensor
   [ INFO] [1339006055.681022434]: Requesting the map...
   [ INFO] [1339006055.683225249]: Still waiting on map...
   [ INFO] [1339006056.684127276]: Still waiting on map...
   [ WARN] [1339006057.693208432]: You have set map parameters, but also requested to use the static map. Your parameters will be overwritten by those given by the map server
   [ INFO] [1339006057.694168703]: Received a 200 X 200 map at 0.005000 m/pix
   [ WARN] [1339006062.734650906]: Waiting on transform from /base_link to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error: 
   [ WARN] [1339006067.778188511]: Waiting on transform from /base_link to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error: 
   [ WARN] [1339006072.821525895]: Waiting on transform from /base_link to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error: 
   [ WARN] [1339006077.858041067]: Waiting on transform from /base_link to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error: 
   [ WARN] [1339006082.896098542]: Waiting on transform from /base_link to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error: 
   [ WARN] [1339006087.945294010]: Waiting on transform from /base_link to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error: 
   [ WARN] [1339006093.020568219]: Waiting on transform from /base_link to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error: 
   [ WARN] [1339006098.075362691]: Waiting on transform from /base_link to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error:
```

Note that after "error:" there is no information as it usually exists when this warning msg shows up (e.g., [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/9928/transform-from-base_link-to-map-navigation-stack)).

So I have analyzed all the param files to check if I got the frame IDs right. Apparently, everything is fine. I thought the problem would be the AMCL because it is responsible for this transformation, but I did not find anything odd in my launch file.

My rxgraph looks like [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/691928/rxgraph.png) (sorry, haven't got karma>20, so cannot post images).

My [param files and AMCL](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/691928/params%20%26%20amcl.zip)  launch.

[rostopic list](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/691928/rostopic%20list.txt)

[roswtf](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/691928/roswtf.txt)

[view_frames](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/691928/frames.pdf) (no map frame...)

I am using ROS Electric.

Please, can someone help me out? If anything else is needed, I will gladly post it later.

Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35844/help-with-navigation---error-%22transform-from-/base_link-to-/map%22/) by [DavidPortugal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1522/davidportugal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 349 on 2012-06-06

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So...after a while, I ended up solving the problem of bringing up the Nav Stack today. The problem was in the "costmap_common_params.yaml" file.

Basically I was setting the robot footprint in cms, instead of using meters. So I was defining a robot that would have a larger size than the map itself :D

Apparently, that was enough for not running the costmap and blow the whole thing up.

Thank you everyone for your feedback!

---

Originally posted by [DavidPortugal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1522/davidportugal/) with karma: 349 on 2012-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to publish a map frame. If I'm correct, your problem is that AMCL is looking for the `/map` frame when it loads your static map from the `map_server`. In order to resolve this problem, you must either set the `frame_id` of your `map_server` to `/odom` or publish the `/map` frame as a parent frame to `/odom`.

```
<node name="map_node" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find my_package)/config/map.yaml" respawn="false">
    <param name="frame_id" value="/odom" />
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-06-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidPortugal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1522/davidportugal/) on 2012-06-08**:
Thank you for your answer Dmitri! Unfortunately, I can only look into it on Monday and I will report about the problem then. Hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, I have tried Dmitri's suggestion (setting */odom* as frame_id of the map server), but the same error persists.

How could I explicitly publish the */map* frame as a parent frame to */odom*? Shouldn't the AMCL be responsible for this transformation?

I've also played around with the AMCL parameter *use_map_topic*, but had no luck.

I am able to bring up the navstack with stage and a static map. Stage is responsible for */odom -> /base_footprint -> /base_link -> /base_laser_link* transformations, while AMCL deals with */map -> /odom*.

Using the robot, my robot_node takes care of */odom -> /base_link* transformation, and I have a static tf_broadcaster taking care of */base_link -> /laser*. But the tf from  */map* to */odom* does not exist =(

I've compared all the parameters (AMCL, Local Planner, Global and Local Costmap) but I am not able to find anything suspicious...

Help please!

---

Originally posted by [DavidPortugal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1522/davidportugal/) with karma: 349 on 2012-06-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidPortugal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1522/davidportugal/) on 2012-06-10**:
Additionally, when i run:

```
tf tf_echo /map /base_link
```

or

```
tf tf_echo /map /odom
```

I receive the following result:

```
Failure at 1339364192.954729563
Exception thrown:Frame id /map does not exist! Frames (4): Frame /base_link exists with parent /odom.
Frame /odom exists with parent N
```

**Comment by [DavidPortugal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1522/davidportugal/) on 2012-06-10**:
Failure at 1339364192.954729563
Exception thrown:Frame id /map does not exist! Frames (4): Frame /base_link exists with parent /odom.
Frame /odom exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /laser exists with parent /base_link.

**Comment by [DavidPortugal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1522/davidportugal/) on 2012-06-10**:
The current list of frames is:
Frame /base_link exists with parent /odom.
Frame /odom exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /laser exists with parent /base_link.

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2012-06-10**:
please, be aware that answers.ros it is not a forum, so it is wrong to post your updates or comments as a new answer. cheers

**Comment by [DavidPortugal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1522/davidportugal/) on 2012-06-10**:
Sorry for that, just wanted to bring in more info to help solving the problem.

**Comment by [Midnight](https://answers.ros.org/users/2270/midnight/) on 2013-05-19**:
I think a more legit way is shifting whatever you are writing here as comments of your original post or just simply edit the original (and adding different edit titles so ppl can trace our progress as well).    Mid

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2018-06-26**:
To explicitly publish /map frame as a parent to /odom frame, one can use the following command-
rosrun tf tf 0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /odom 100 , where {0 , 0 , 0} -> translational transform, and {0 0 0 } -> rotational transform

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you setting your robot initial pose? That's one way you can get your /map to /odom transformation. AMCL will only correct that transformation based on other sensor readings.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2012-06-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidPortugal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1522/davidportugal/) on 2012-06-10**:
Yes, at the AMCL launch file:

I can also see the map in Rviz, but I get the following error there:
.Global Status: Error
Fixed Frame [/map] does not exist